# an error "variable of field declared void"

Tags: c++

I have this code:

#### header - test.h

Inside header I have some class A and definitions of two functions quiz and quiz2

```
void quiz(int i);

void quiz2(A a, A const *pa);
```

I call function quiz2 from quiz

```
A a1(i);
A *pa1 = new A(a1);
quiz2(a1, pa1);
```

this is implementation of the function:

```
  void quiz2(A a, A const *pa){
        int i = a;
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

but in my header I receive 3 errors near the line of definition of quiz2:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - initializer expression list treated as compound 
     expression
    - `A' was not declared in this scope
    - variable or field `quiz2' declared void
```

can somebody please explain why? thanks in advance

Comment: there's no variable quiz2 in your example. Please have a look at the lines numbers indicated by compiler.

Comment: Since neither `A` nor `quiz2` appear in the code you've shown, I have to assume, you didn't actually show us the part of the code that causes the error.

Comment: It's not the code that you've posted. You'll need to show more of the header including line numbers, and give us the line number from the compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that I must declare firstly classes and only after that functions, so now it's working

Comment: When making updates like this, please edit the original post.  SO is not a forum or blog.

Comment: But @John, this isn't just an update to the question. It's the *answer* to the question. His failure to declare things in the right order is what caused the compiler errors. The solution to the errors was to change the declaration order. This answer could be phrased better, but it's still an answer. +1.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy:  Fair enough, removed d/v